# Select language for JRE installer

Tags: java

I'm creating an installer for a Java application and i must include the JRE Offline Installer. I actually downloaded a copy of the installer from the official Oracle page

[Java English Download Page](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)

but i still get an installer which shows another language ( Italian ).
Is there a way to change it? Or does it depend on the operative system language?

Comment: what do you mean "creating an installer"?

Comment: I'm creating a software which installs another software made by me.

Comment: ok, what is your operative system language?

Comment: I don't think that there are jre installers for each local. You may have configured your local to italian

Comment: I do have an italian language OS. Are you sure or do you have any proof that the java installer takes the local language to choose its language?